# How to force calculating of SUM when row is empty

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have issue that I want to calculate SUM for every product for whole year.
But thing is that sum is not calculating in cases that slicer is not triggering month that contains values.

In other words: I want get top-left pivot look like bottom-left pivot, so slicer would be totally ignored
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a connectorTbl table like this

```
| Year | Month | firstDayCalendar |
|------|-------|------------------|
| 2019 | 1     | 1/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 2     | 2/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 3     | 3/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 4     | 4/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 5     | 5/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 6     | 6/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 7     | 7/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 8     | 8/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 9     | 9/1/2019         |
| 2019 | 10    | 10/1/2019        |
| 2019 | 11    | 11/1/2019        |
| 2019 | 12    | 12/1/2019        |
| 2020 | 1     | 1/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 2     | 2/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 3     | 3/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 4     | 4/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 5     | 5/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 6     | 6/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 7     | 7/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 8     | 8/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 9     | 9/1/2020         |
| 2020 | 10    | 10/1/2020        |
| 2020 | 11    | 11/1/2020        |
| 2020 | 12    | 12/1/2020        |
```

and create a column in the fact table like this `

```
| ID  | Year | Month | VAL | firstDay  |
|-----|------|-------|-----|-----------|
| AAA | 2019 | 10    | 101 | 10/1/2019 |
| AAA | 2019 | 11    | 102 | 11/1/2019 |
| AAA | 2019 | 12    | 103 | 12/1/2019 |
| AAA | 2020 | 1     | 4   | 1/1/2020  |
| AAA | 2020 | 2     | 5   | 2/1/2020  |
| AAA | 2020 | 3     | 6   | 3/1/2020  |
| AAA | 2020 | 4     | 7   | 4/1/2020  |
| AAA | 2020 | 5     | 8   | 5/1/2020  |
| AAA | 2020 | 6     | 9   | 6/1/2020  |
| BBB | 2019 | 1     | 1   | 1/1/2019  |
| BBB | 2020 | 12    | 1   | 12/1/2020 |
```

create a relationship between fact and connector on `firstDayCalendar` and then the measure will work as desired
[image: Solution]

Also, for all your future posts please provide the sample data and desired output in markdown tables [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)